# Bridge Problems

Tags: networking, bridge

I have a router that the ISP gave me, its an Arris TG862 that has internet connection and I have my old router, Linksys E2500, that I use in bridge mode, then all of the sudden my 2 routers stop communicating, what do I mean by this:

I have my LAN cable from an Ethernet Port of my Arris to the Internet Port of the Linksys but the LED on the back wont turn on. Then I told to myself that maybe the cable is damaged and went ahead and pluged in my laptop to that same Ethernet cable and it worked, then I told myself "well the port on the bridge does not work" and got another LAN cable and tested all 5 ports on the bridge and they all turned on, the only way the port on the back of my router and bridge mode don't turn on its by connecting them together.

Comment: From what I think I know, the Linksys will treat its "Internet" connector always with the same pin assignment, so it may be required to use a crossover ethernet cable between the Arris and the Linksys. Of course, you could also try an autodetecting hub between them.

Answer (score 1):

Would be too many posts to put as a comment, so I'll have to put here.

> I have my LAN cable from an Ethernet Port of my Arris to the Internet Port of the Linksys ***but the LED on the back wont turn on***

Which LED doesn't turn on?  The one on the Arris or the Linksys?

> Then I told to myself that maybe the cable is damaged and went ahead and pluged in my laptop to that same Ethernet cable and it worked

Plugged Ethernet cable into what?  The Linksys or the Arris?  If you plugged it into the Arris were you able to get out to the internet?  If you can hook up that way again and tell us what IP address you are getting.

If you are getting a 192.168.x.x address from the Arris then it's resorted back to it's default setting of being a Modem/Router.  I think the default for them is 192.168.0.1 for the router address.

Those Arris modems can be setup a couple different ways, and I have a lot of those in my area.  Rarely, I've seen them forget their settings and change their mode.

Unless the modem has just gone bad, it should take your ISP support 10 minutes or so to get it set back to the config you want.